# Xtext, making the difference between ID and String at the interpreter

Tags: dsl, xtext, xtend

I'm writing a dsl in a text in which people can declare some variables. the grammar is as follows:

```
Cosem:
cosem+=ID '=' 'COSEM' '(' class=INT ',' version=INT ','  obis=STRING ')' ;
Attributes :
attribute+=ID '=' 'ATTRIBUTE' '(' object=ID ',' attribute_name=STRING ')' ;
Action:
action+=ID '=' 'ACTION' '(' object=ID ',' action_name=STRING ')';
```

the Dsl has some methods like the print method:

```
Print: 
'PRINT' '('  var0=(STRING|ID) (','var1+=(STRING|ID) )* ')' |
'PRINT' '(' ')'
```

;

I put all my variables in map so I can use them later in my code. the key is identifying them is their ID which is a string.
However, in my interpreter I can't make the différence between a string and an ID

```
def dispatch void exec(Print p) {

    if (LocalMapAttribute.containsKey(p.var0) )
     {print(LocalMapAttribute.get(p.var0))}
    else if (LocalMapAction.containsKey(p.var0)){print(LocalMapAction.get(p.var0))}
    else if (LocalMapCosem.containsKey(p.var0)){print(LocalMapCosem.get(p.var0))}
    else
    {print("erreeeur Print")}

     p.var1.forEach[v
        | if (LocalMapAttribute.containsKey(v)){print(LocalMapAttribute.get(v))}
                       else if (LocalMapAction.containsKey(v)){print(LocalMapAction.get(v))}
                       else if (LocalMapCosem.containsKey(v)){print(LocalMapCosem.get(v))} 
                       else{print("erreur entre print")} ]
}
```

For example when I write `PRINT ("attribut2",attribut2)` the result shoud be

```
attribut2 "the value of attribut2"
```

but I get

```
"the value of attribut2" "the value of attribut2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your current grammar structure makes it hard to do this since you throw away the information at the point where you fill the map.

you can use `org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.util.NodeModelUtils.findNodesForFeature(EObject, EStructuralFeature)` to obtain the actual text (which still may contain the original value including the `""`

or you change your grammar to

```
var0=Value ...
Value: IDValue | StringValue;
IDValue: value=ID;
StringValue: value=STRING;
```

then you can have a look at the type (IDValue or StringValue) to decide wheather you need to put the text into `""` (`org.eclipse.xtext.util.Strings.convertToJavaString(String, boolean)`) might be helpful

Or you can try to use a special replacement for STRINGValueaConcerter that does not strip the quotation marks

Comment: thank you for Answer, it does work. how could I validate it? or I can't because of my low reputation?

Comment: looks like you found it